# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 1 instance of jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration but got 0

Tags: jenkins

```
WARNING h.i.i.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler#handleException: Caught unhandled exception with ID ac14aaf0-3df5-4859-b1a3-4f1e2b46849a
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 1 instance of jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration but got 0
at hudson.ExtensionList.lookupSingleton(ExtensionList.java:454)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration.get(ResourceDomainConfiguration.java:267)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration.isResourceDomainConfigured(ResourceDomainConfiguration.java:257)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainConfiguration.isResourceRequest(ResourceDomainConfiguration.java:220)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:71)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:47)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(Excep

While upgrading Jenkins image from 2.346.3 to 3.375.4 LTS version i am getting this error. I have tried different images & upgraded plugins as well but no luck . Can anyone have any clue or suggestion ?

thanks in advance.